# Unbound breakpoints in Vscode 1.64.2

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm using vscode with Angular, and I'm unable to set breakpoints that trigger. All breakpoints are set as unbound breakpoints.

My environment:

> Version: 1.64.2 (user setup) Date:
> 2022-02-09T22:02:28.252Z Electron: 13.5.2 Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
> Node.js: 14.16.0 V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0 OS: Windows_NT x64
> 10.0.22000

my launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
      "name": "ng serve",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}", 
      //"sourceMaps": 
      "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "!**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
    "trace": true
    },
    {
      "name": "ng test",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "./src/*": "${workspaceFolder}/src/*"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "ng e2e",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
      "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/e2e/protractor.conf.js"]
    },
    
  ]
```

}

I've tried a number of things that I've found on stackoverflow and various documents :

- added sourcemap: true in tsconfig.json

  {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "strict": true,
  "noImplicitOverride": true,
  "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
  "noImplicitReturns": true,
  "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "downlevelIteration": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "importHelpers": true,
  "target": "es2017",
  "module": "es2020",
  "lib": [
  "es2020",
  "dom"
  ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
  "strictInjectionParameters": true,
  "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
  "strictTemplates": true
  }
  }
- added the following in angular.json "vendorChunk": true,
  "extractLicenses": false,
  "buildOptimizer": false,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "optimization": false,
  "namedChunks": true
- added the resolveSourceMapLocations option in lauch.json settings for 'ng serve'.
- added outfiles option in launch.json settings for 'ng serve'.

None of these have worked and my breakpoints still remain unbound, even when my angular component with the breakpoint is loaded.

Question : How do I enable debugging in VSCode for angular so that breakpoints are not unbound and breaks at the breakpoint ?

Comment: Make sure `webRoot` is pointing to the root directory which is accessible via `http://localhost:9876/` In my case my `workspaceFolder` was `/htdocs/test/`, so I had to use `"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/../"`

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced breakpoints all being unbound with 1.64.2. I downgraded to 1.63.2 and my breakpoints work now. Hopefully you're dealing with the same cause.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, I downloaded that version and unfortunately the breakpoints still remain unbound.